# How can I add the context menu and the Ribbon tab in the same Ribbon.xml

Tags: .net, xml, c#-4.0, vsto, ribbon

I am implementing a new addin for Office 2010. How to add the context menu
and the Ribbon tab in the same Ribbon.xml file?
I tried adding the ribbon and the context menu in the same Ribbon_Load onAction,
but the context menu is not created at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"           onLoad="Ribbon_Load" loadImage="Ribbon_LoadImage">
 <ribbon>
<tabs>
  <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
    <group id="groupExcel" label="Excel" keytip="P">         
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon> 
<contextMenus>
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuText">
  <button idMso="FontDialog" visible="true" />
  <toggleButton id="MyToggle" label="My Toggle Button" />
  <button id="MyButton" label="My Button" insertBeforeMso="HyperlinkInsert"        onAction="mycontent" />
  <menuSeparator id="MySeparator" />
  <menu id="MySubMenu" label="My Submenu" >
    <button id="MyButton2" label="Button on submenu" />
  </menu>
  <dynamicMenu id="MyDynamicMenu" label= "My Dynamic Menu" getContent="GetMyContent" />
</contextMenu>
</contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

But I can see that the context menu is not loading nor visible in after clicking right on one of the cell.
I am using .net c# 4.0 VSTO 2010

Please help me in this
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am able to achieve this.

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuText">
```

I changed ContextMenuText to ContextMenuCell.

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">
```